# Is there any equivalent to Oracle DBMS_SQL functions in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are doing migrate data from Oracle database to Azure Cloud (ADLS2 & SQL Pool which is a SQL Server). So I need to convert PL/SQL script into T/SQL, and got trouble in this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function ITSHBHO.getlong( p_tname in varchar2, 
                                        p_cname in varchar2, 
                                        p_rowid in rowid ) return varchar2 
   as 
       l_cursor    integer default dbms_sql.open_cursor; 
       l_n         number; 
       l_long_val  varchar2(32000); 
       l_long_len  number; 
       l_buflen    number := 4000; 
       l_curpos    number := 0; 
   begin 
       dbms_sql.parse( l_cursor, 'select ' || p_cname || ' from ' || p_tname || ' where rowid = :x', dbms_sql.native ); 
       dbms_sql.bind_variable( l_cursor, ':x', p_rowid ); 
    
       dbms_sql.define_column_long(l_cursor, 1); 
       l_n := dbms_sql.execute(l_cursor); 
    
       if (dbms_sql.fetch_rows(l_cursor)>0) 
       then 
          dbms_sql.column_value_long(l_cursor, 1, l_buflen, l_curpos , l_long_val, l_long_len ); 
      end if; 
      dbms_sql.close_cursor(l_cursor); 
      return l_long_val; 
 end getlong;
/
```

Is there anyway to convert this script into T/SQL?

Comment: Only tag the RDBMS you want your solution in. And please let us know what research you have done and what particular bits you are stuck on.

Comment: Yes I agree this looks like it would be a difficult one to convert. It seems to have dynamic sql in it, that is something you simply cannot do in a function in sql server.  It seems that the design of the database has gone horribly wrong when you don't know the name of the table or even the column name you want to select in a function.

Comment: You don't need a cursor - this is basically doing "select col from table where id = <param>".  You can just run that query directly without a function if you'd like.  As noted, SQL doesn't support dynamic SQL in a function (and this is not a great case to re-think that - if you inline this in a bigger query, SQL can do a better job at join ordering to pick an efficient execution plan)